# How to add category to create post using rest-api

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, wordpress-rest-api

I am creating post in wp rest API from front end of my website. I want to add drop down on front end that display all categories and user user select any one to submit post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
   'orderby' => 'name',
   'order'   => 'ASC'
) );
```

Comment: i want to make select drop down on front end and add these categories in it